# Access-Control-Allow-Origin when trying to invoke Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, xss, google-cloud-functions

I'm sure this is simple, but isn't the whole point of firebase's functions to allow me to call functions via client-side code to run on the server-side? If I send HTTP requests to the address from my app to the function address, I just get 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' errors. How is javascript supposed to call these functions from the client-side?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#use_middleware_modules_with_cloud_functions. If that doesn't work, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to allow cross-origin HTTP requests.  There is [official sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/time-server) that demonstrates how to use the [cors node.js module](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) to enable that.

Alternately, if you're using Firebase Hosting to host your app, you can expose your HTTP functions under your site domain so that all requests to the function appear to come from the same domain.

Comment: how do you "expose your HTTP functions under your site domain so that all requests to the function appear to come from the same domain." (I am using Firebase Hosting to host my app) @doug-stevenson